# Why mulh instruction in riscv32 gives 0?

Tags: assembly, riscv, riscv32

```
Multiplier = 0xffffffff
Multiplicand = 0xffffffff
Result = 0xFFFFFFFE 00000001 (multiplier * multiplicand)
```

`mulh` instruction is expected to give the upper XLEN bits of the result as per RISC-Vs pec. But when I run `mulh t0, a0, a1;` with multiplier  in `a0` and multiplicand in `a1`, the result in `t0` is 0. Can someone explain why?  I run this in RV32IMAC (FE310 core).

assembly and C code below:

```
mulh_asm:
    mulh t0, a0, a1;
    addi a0, x0, 0; // **Break point here to watch t0 value**
ret;

mrest[0] = mulh_asm(0xffffffff,  0xffffffff);
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include a minimal compilable example that reproduces the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the result in t0 is 0. Can someone explain why?

`mulh` is for signed × signed, so you're doing -1 × -1!  The result for which is +1, and in 64 bits, that is 63-bits of zeros followed by a 1 bit — so naturally the proper answer for the upper 32 bits (of 64-bit +1) is all zeros.

> [Desired] Result = 0xFFFFFFFE 00000001 (multiplier * multiplicand)

Try `mulhu`, which is for unsigned × unsigned, and this will give you the results you're expecting.